# Index of the Intersection of Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are distinct subgroups of a group
$G$ such that $[G : H_1] = [G : H_2] = 3$. What are the possible values of
$[G:H_1 \cap H_2]$?

Reading the solution - So you can let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be the sets of left cosets of $H_1$ and $H_2$ in $G$, respectively. I get that G acts upon $S_1 \times S_2$ by left multiplication and the stabilizer of $(H_1, H_2)$ is $H_1 \cap H_2$. Why must  $[G: H_1 \cap H_2] \leq 9$?

Edit: So with the help of Jyrki I see why it's bounded by 9. The solution says that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are distinct subgroups of the same index, so this implies that $H_1$ is not contained in $H_2$, and (this is where I get lost) that $[G:H_1 \cap H_2]$ is a proper multiple of $[G:H_1] = 3$.

Comment: I think the action of $G$ on $S_1\times S_2$ is one coming from left multiplication (conjugation does not act on the cosets), and it would be better to say *the stabilizer of the element $(H_1,H_2)$ is $H_1\cap H_2$.

Comment: Anyway, both $S_1$ and $S_2$ have three elements each, so $S_1\times S_2$ has nine elements. I guess you are expected to apply the orbit-stabilizer theorem to $G$ and $(H_1,H_2)\in S_1\times S_2$.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that first point.

Comment: The intersection is a proper subgroup of either subgroup, so the index of the intersection is a proper multiple of the index of either subgroup by Lagrange.

Comment: Ah yes! Thanks to both of you. This has been very helpful.

Comment: For full credit I guess you are expected to exhibit examples of $G,H_1,H_2$- one for each allowed proper multiple of three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [orbit-stabilizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma),$$\frac{|G|}{|H_1\cap H_2|}=[G:H_1\cap H_2]=|\operatorname{Orb}(H_1\cap H_2)|\leqslant\#(S_1\times S_2)=9.$$On the other hand $[G:H_1\cap H_2]=[G:H_1]\times[H_1:H_1\cap H_2]=3[H_1:H_1\cap H_2]$. Since $[G:H_1\cap H_2]\leqslant 9$ and $[G:H_1\cap H_2]$ is a multiple of $3$, $[G:H_1\cap H_2]$ must be $3$, $6$ or $9$.
Since $[H_1:H_1\cap H_2]>1$ we can rule out $3$.

And, yes, both the cases $6$ and $9$ can actually occur.